# Update LogLevel from code without using log4j-core

Tags: java, log4j2

I want to update log level programmatically without using log4j-core. Can it be done using log4j-api.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically updating the log level can be done if you set up your log4j2 configuration to use a [DynamicThresholdFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html#DynamicThresholdFilter). Here is a simple example:

First, a log4j2.xml file to configure the log4j2 system:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
            <DynamicThresholdFilter key="myLogLvl" defaultThreshold="ERROR"
                                      onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY">
                <KeyValuePair key="TRACE" value="TRACE"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="DEBUG" value="DEBUG"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="INFO" value="INFO"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="WARN" value="WARN"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="FATAL" value="FATAL"/>
              </DynamicThresholdFilter>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Notice how I have set up the filter so that the `DynamicThresholdFilter` has a key of "myLogLvl" and then several `KeyValuePair` that define the log level threshold based on the value in `ThreadContext` for the key "myLogLvl". I assumed you wanted to use the names of the levels as the value you would put into `ThreadContext`.

Also notice that I have set the `Root` logger's level to "ALL". This is so that all messages will be accepted by the logger and then filtered by the filter. In other words I'm putting the filter in control of which messages are accepted rather than the logger.

Here is a simple Java class to generate some logs:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ThreadContext.put("myLogLvl", "WARN");

        if(log.isDebugEnabled())
            log.debug("This is some debug! (This should not appear in console)");
        log.info("Here's some info! (This should not appear in console)");
        log.error("Some error happened! (We will see this in the console)");

        //Maybe now I want INFO log level
        ThreadContext.put("myLogLvl", "INFO");

        log.info("This should now appear in the console");
        log.debug("This still should --not-- appear");
        log.fatal("This will also appear");
    }
}
```

Notice the first I do is set the `ThreadContext` variable "myLogLvl" to "WARN" so that only messages that are "WARN" level or more specific are accepted. If you don't do this there will be no value for "myLogLvl" which means the default level defined in the filter will not apply either, so all messages will be accepted.

Here is sample output generated by the above:

```
10:39:44.668 [main] ERROR example.SomeClass - Some error happened! (We will see this in the console)
10:39:44.670 [main] INFO  example.SomeClass - This should now appear in the console
10:39:44.670 [main] FATAL example.SomeClass - This will also appear
```

Hope this helps!